# Problem in Facebook API?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have created an app and I am using the Facebook API from [this site](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-facebook-api-example-using-fbrocket/#idc-cover).

It shows the login page, but when I give the username and password and it shows the error "Sorry something went wrong......." with a "go back" button.  Using that button only, I can go to my main page after a long time.

I want to solve this problem and I want to post some message immediately when I hit the login button.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think facebook is facing some issues. This message appears to me and a lot of friends when viewing any "note" on Facebook.